# Resources for Linear Algebra and Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble understanding linear algebra and subspaces.

The following question in particular is one I am stuck on:

Let {U<sub>n</sub> : n $\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be a family of subspaces of R<sup>m</sup>. 

Show that if U<sub>n</sub> $\subseteq$ U<sub>n+1</sub> for all n $\in\mathbb{N}$ then S := $\cup$<sub>n $\in$ N</sub> U<sub>n</sub> is a subspace of R<sup>m</sup>.

Are there any good or recommendable resources to help better understand this question and to be able to answer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x,y\in S$ and $a\in R$. For $S$ to be a subspace we need to show that $ax\in S$ and $x+y\in S$. But indeed, $x\in U_n$ and $y\in U_k$ for some $k,n\in N$. Then $x,y\in U_{\max\{k,n\}}$, and this is a subspace, therefore $ax,x+y\in U_{\max\{k,n\}}\subseteq S$.

It seems to me that you are having trouble from the very concept of a vector space. I would recommend you to take a look at some linear algebra book with a pure mathematical approach; for instance Hoffman & Kunze.